# How can I set a column based on a condition in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a column which I need to set to true or false based on a condition, is this possible to do as part of an existing update?

Example:

```
UPDATE  i
SET     i.Outstanding = i.Total - @Payments,
    i.Paid = @Payments ,
    i.Closed = (i.Total <= @Payments) -- THIS DOESNT WORK :(
FROM    Invoice i
JOIN    [Transaction] t ON t.Invoice_Id = i.Id
WHERE   i.Id = @InvoiceId
```

Comment: use [case](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) statement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `CASE` statement

```
UPDATE  i
SET     i.Outstanding = i.Total - @Payments,
    i.Paid = @Payments ,
    i.Closed = CASE WHEN i.Total <= @Payments THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
FROM    Invoice i
JOIN    [Transaction] t ON t.Invoice_Id = i.Id
WHERE   i.Id = @InvoiceId
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple case statement like below

```
UPDATE  i
SET     i.Outstanding = i.Total - @Payments,
i.Paid = @Payments ,
i.Closed = CASE WHEN i.Total <= @Payments THEN 'Your value' ELSE 'your value' END
FROM    Invoice i
JOIN    [Transaction] t ON t.Invoice_Id = i.Id
WHERE   i.Id = @InvoiceId
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
UPDATE  i
SET     i.Outstanding = i.Total - @Payments,
    i.Paid = @Payments ,
    i.Closed = CASE WHEN i.Total <= @Payments THEN 'true' ELSE 'false' END
FROM    Invoice i
JOIN    [Transaction] t ON t.Invoice_Id = i.Id
WHERE   i.Id = @InvoiceId
```

CASE Syntax:

```
CASE input_expression 
     WHEN when_expression THEN result_expression [ ...n ] 
     [ ELSE else_result_expression ] 
END
```

Read more about CASE [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx).